# how to hide the button based on a condition? odoo 11

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to hide the "create invoice" button (in quotation view) based on a condition if the command line has a task/service, I tried this code but it does not work :

```
<button name="%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"
                    type="action" context="{'default_advance_payment_method': 'percentage'}"
                    attrs="{'invisible': ['|','|', ('task_ids', '=', []), ('invoice_status', '!=', 'no'), ('state', '!=', 'sale')]}"/>
```

Comment: Looks fine for me. Which Odoo version do you use? Is `task_ids` present in the view (at least invisible)?

Comment: Sorry @CZoellner, I use Odoo 11, i want juste hide button create invoice if order line has task/service

Comment: You didn't answer my second question.

Comment: Yes tasks_ids, there's but invisible, there's also project_ids but also invisible unless order line has a service that is a task

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style, `display: none` to a button to hide it

Comment: but not for condition this solution, if i use ``display``, it's hiding for all quotation view no !

Comment: You can use style per condition, when the condition doesnt satisfy what you need simply dont use display: none, otherwise you can use it

Answer (score 0):

You can write a button like the following:

```
  <button name="%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"
                type="action" context="{'default_advance_payment_method': 'percentage'}"
                attrs="{'invisible': ['|','|', ('task_ids', '=', False), ('invoice_status', '!=', 'no'), ('state', '!=', 'sale')]}"/>
```