# How hide button based on condition ? (ODOO 11)

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Please help me, i want to hide button "Invoice Order" if in order line there's task/service,  is there a function on python or a thread on XML ?

thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to hide the button based on a condition? odoo 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593185/how-to-hide-the-button-based-on-a-condition-odoo-11)

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs more info. What language/library is being used to create the button? If Odoo (tagged in your question) then you can set the button to invisible in its attributes

```
<button string="<Button text>" type="object" name="<button-name for code>" attrs="{'invisible': [(<condition when to be invisible>)]}"/>
```

Code snippet provided by this tutorial in the second half of the "Creating the view" section: [odoo tutorial](http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/creating-and-managing-statusbars-selections-in-odoo/)